# Invalid rank in master-worker dynamic load balancing

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a master-worker dynamic load balancing which it works fine in my computer, but When I am trying to run my program on super computer I am getting invalid rank error for sending the job from master in this block:

```
  while (mesg[0] < nindices) {
    MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, comm, &status);
    int isource = status.MPI_SOURCE;
    MPI_Recv(recv_mesg, 1, MPI_INT, isource, 1, comm, &status);
    MPI_Send(mesg, 1, MPI_INT, isource, 1, comm);
    mesg[0] += 1;
  }
```

If the number of jobs are 2 or 3 and I have one worker and one master, it works absolutely fine! (even in the super computer) but when I increase the number of jobs to 4 and higher, I will get the invalid rank error

the sample code is:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_SIZE 1

void function_test(MPI_Comm comm) {
  int mpi_world_size;
MPI_Comm_size(comm, &mpi_world_size);
int mpi_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &mpi_rank);

  std::cout<<"hi"<<std::endl;
  int nindices =3;

  if (nindices > 0) {
    if(mpi_rank == 0) {
      MPI_Status status;

      int mesg[1]={0};
      int initial_id = 0;
      int recv_mesg[1]={0};

      //-- send out initial ids to workers --//
      while (initial_id < mpi_world_size - 1) {
        if (initial_id < nindices) {
          MPI_Send(mesg, 1, MPI_INT, initial_id + 1, 1, comm);
          mesg[0] += 1;
          ++initial_id;
        }
      }

      //--  id to workers dynamically --//
      while (mesg[0] < nindices) {
        MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, comm, &status);
        int isource = status.MPI_SOURCE;
        MPI_Recv(recv_mesg, 1, MPI_INT, isource, 1, comm, &status);
        MPI_Send(mesg, 1, MPI_INT, isource, 1, comm);
        mesg[0] += 1;
      }

      //-- ending signals--//
      for (int rank = 1; rank < mpi_world_size; ++rank) {
        mesg[0] = -1;
        MPI_Send(mesg, 1, MPI_INT, rank, 0, comm);
      }
    } else { // worker
      MPI_Status status;
      int id[1]={0};
      while(true) {
        
        MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, comm, &status);
        int itag = status.MPI_TAG;
        MPI_Recv(id, 1, MPI_INT, 0, itag, comm, &status);

        int jindex = id[0];
        if (jindex < 0) break;
        MPI_Send(id, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, comm);
      }
    }
  }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // MPI Start
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  int world_rank, world_size;
  MPI_Comm world_comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;

  int color_rank_count = 3;
  // ****************************************************************************** Geting the size and rank of the world_comm
  MPI_Comm_rank(world_comm, &world_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(world_comm, &world_size);

  // ****************************************************************************** Creat two commiunicators
  MPI_Comm c_comm;
  MPI_Comm c_comm_0;

  int color_integral =
      (world_rank == 0)
          ? 0
          : 1 + static_cast<int>(floor((world_rank - 1) / color_rank_count));
  int key_integral =
      (world_rank == 0) ? 0 : (world_rank - 1) % color_rank_count;
  int color_zeros =
      (world_rank == 0) ? 0 : (world_rank - 1) % color_rank_count;
  int key_zeros =
      (world_rank == 0)
          ? 0
          : 1 + static_cast<int>(floor((world_rank - 1) / color_rank_count));


  MPI_Comm_split(world_comm, color_integral, key_integral,
                 &c_comm);
  MPI_Comm_split(world_comm, color_zeros, key_zeros, &c_comm_0);

  int c_size, c_0_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(c_comm, &c_size);
  MPI_Comm_size(c_comm_0, &c_0_size);

  int c_rank, c_0_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(c_comm, &c_rank);
  MPI_Comm_rank(c_comm_0, &c_0_rank);


  if (world_rank == 0) { // controller rank
        int mesg[1] = {0};
            int nindices = 3;
           int initial_task = 0;
           int nProc = c_0_size;
           bool recv_mesg[1]={true};
           //-- send out initial tasks to slaves --//
           while (initial_task < c_0_size - 1) {
             if (initial_task < nindices) {
               MPI_Send(mesg, 1, MPI_INT, initial_task + 1, 1, c_comm_0);
               mesg[0] += 1;
               ++initial_task;
             }
           }
             int proc = initial_task;
             //-- hand out quartets to slaves dynamically --//
             while (mesg[0] != nindices) {
               if(proc >= nProc) {
                 proc = 1;
               }
               MPI_Send(mesg, 1, MPI_INT, proc, 1, c_comm_0);
               ++proc;
               mesg[0] += 1;

             }
        //-- hand out ending signals once done --//
        for (int rank = 1; rank < c_0_size; ++rank) {
          mesg[0] = -1;
          MPI_Send(mesg, 1, MPI_INT, rank, 0, c_comm_0);
        }

      } else { // worker ranks
      MPI_Status status;
      int task[1]={0};

      while (true) {
        if (color_zeros == 0) {
          MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, c_comm_0, &status);
          int isource = status.MPI_SOURCE;
          int itag = status.MPI_TAG;
          MPI_Recv(task, 1, MPI_INT, isource, itag, c_comm_0, &status);
        }
        MPI_Barrier(c_comm);
        MPI_Bcast(task, 1, MPI_INT, 0, c_comm);

        int ifrag = task[0];

        if (ifrag < 0)
          break;
          function_test(c_comm);

         }
       }

  /* All done */
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;

}
```

P.S. In the code I had to split the ranks for my purpose, and this is the simple skeleton of the MPI that I have to use.

Comment: Print is always you friend in debugging! Print out the values of `isource` and that will help you see if it is maybe just one larger than expected or a competely random value.

Comment: You say it works for 2 or 3 processes. Then it is very suspicious that there is an `int nindices=3` that controls how many messages are being sent initially. My guess is that your second while loop in main is conceptually wrong, and it is never executed as long as you have only 3 processes. This is messy code! Between the multiple while loops, it is easy to get the logic wrong. (And please don't use the word "slave". "Worker" will do fine.)